# export NODE_PATH after node executable is run

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

Is there a way to set the NODE_PATH env variable after node has started?

if I do this:

```
async.series([
        function export_NODE_PATH(cb){
          cp.exec('export NODE_PATH=$(npm root -g):$NODE_PATH',cb);
        },...
```

it won't work, but if I set NODE_PATH before starting node, it will work as expected

```
export NODE_PATH=$(npm root -g):$NODE_PATH && node index --transpile test
```

is there a way to set the environment variable in the node.js runtime, without the need to set it at the command line before executing? Is it as simple as setting process.env.NODE_PATH during runtime?

For example, this seems to work:

```
    cp.exec('echo $(npm root -g)', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err || String(stdout).match(/error/i) || String(stderr).match(/error/i)) {
        cb(err || stdout || stderr);  // my funky way of handling this
    }
    else {
        process.env.NODE_PATH += stdout;
        cb(null);
     }
    });
```

but I don't know how kosher that is, and it does not actually seem to work, after further testing.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is by creating an .env file and using a npm library called dotenv to load the .env files variables into your process.env automatically. Steps include the following:

Step 1:
  Create an .env file in your project directory `$ touch .env`

Step 2: place the following text in your .env file "`NODE_ENV=yourvaluehere`" (without quotes)

Step 3:
 Install dotenv `$ npm install dotenv --save`

Step 3:
 In the js file you run to start the server, add the following `require('dotenv').config();`

Viola, you are now setting environment variables in your node process via an env file. Your `process.env` will have all key value pairs stored in your `.env` file!

Answer (score 1):

Setting `process.env.NODE_PATH` (or any other env var) is perfectly "legal" - in fact that's how libraries such as `dotenv` and `yenv` do their magic.

Comment: given some testing I have just done, reassigning process.env.NODE_PATH during runtime does not seem to work, I am looking at the source code of the libs you mentioned to figure out how they do it, if you know, however please augment your answer thx!

Comment: Make sure you assign it before its being used - not sure if NODE_PATH is special though

Comment: I have the same problem as Alexander Mills. In my case NODE_PATH is certainly set to `./` but it does not affect the module resolution, unless it had this value from the very beginning (from CLI)! create-react-app is using this differently then just setting process.env.NODE_PATH on the fly.